# SQL: Names of courses that Mike can take next semester

Tags: sql

Mike can take a CS course X only if he has not successfully finished X, or he has successfully finished all the courses on which course X is built. For example, Mike cannot take IE2900, because he has not successfully finished IE2700.
(In the query, only the courses on which a course is *directly* built should be considered. For example, IE3200 is only directly built on IE2201, not on IE1100).

In short, find a query for codes of CS courses that Mike can take next semester.

The result should be like the following:

```
Code
----
IE2700
IE3200
```

Below are the database tables with example data:

Students

```
Sid         Name      
----------  ----------
2           Kathlyn     
6           Mike       
7           Nick       
9           Anny
```

Courses

```
Code        Title        Dept        Credits   
----------  -----------  ----------  ----------
IE1100      programming  CS          10        
IE2201      operating s  CS          20        
IE2700      database     CS          10        
IE2900      software en  CS          10        
IE3200      distributed  CS          10        
MAT1001     calculus     Math        30        
DOK1012     database     Hum         10
```

CoursesBuiltOn

```
Code        BuiltOn   
----------  ----------
IE2201      IE1100   
IE2700      IE1100   
IE2900      IE2201   
IE2900      IE2700   
IE3200      IE2201
```

Grades

```
Sid         Code        Year        Grade     
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
2           MAT1001     2010        A         
2           IE1100      2011        A         
2           IE2201      2012        A         
2           IE2700      2013        A         
2           IE2900      2014        B         
2           IE3200      2014        B         
6           MAT1001     2011        D         
6           IE1100      2012        C         
6           IE2201      2013        B         
6           IE2700      2013        F         
7           MAT1001     2013        B         
7           DOK1012     2013        A         
9           MAT1001     2013        F
```

The database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Students (
Sid TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
Name TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE Courses (
Code TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
Title TEXT,
Dept TEXT,
Credits INT
);
CREATE TABLE Grades (
Sid INT,
Code TEXT,
Year INT,
Grade TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (Sid, Code),
FOREIGN KEY (Sid) REFERENCES Students (Sid),
FOREIGN KEY (Code) REFERENCES Courses (Code)
);
CREATE TABLE CoursesBuiltOn (
Code TEXT,
BuiltOn TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (Code, BuiltOn),
FOREIGN KEY (Code) REFERENCES Courses (Code),
FOREIGN KEY (Code) REFERENCES Courses (BuiltOn)
);
```

I tried to join all the tables together on their foreign keys and get out information, but I could not find any way to get the right answer.

### EDIT:

This is what I got so far:

```
with NotAvailable as (select COB.Code
from Courses C
left join CoursesBuiltOn COB on COB.BuiltOn = C.Code
left join Grades Gr on Gr.Code = C.Code
inner join Students S on S.Sid = Gr.Sid
where Gr.Sid = S.Sid and Gr.Grade = 'F'
), AlreadyTakenAndPassed as (select Gr.Code 
from Grades Gr where Gr.Sid = S.Sid and Gr.Grade <> 'F'
), TakenButNotYetPassed as (select Gr.Code 
from Grades Gr where Gr.Sid = S.Sid and Gr.Grade = 'F'
)
select COB.Code
from Courses C
left join CoursesBuiltOn COB on COB.BuiltOn = C.Code
left join Grades G on G.Code = C.Code
inner join Students S on G.Sid = S.Sid
where C.Dept = 'CS' and S.Name = 'Mike'
and (COB.Code in TakenButNotYetPassed or COB.Code not in NotAvailable or COB.Code not in AlreadyTakenAndPassed)
;

Code      
----------
IE2700   
IE2900   
IE3200   
IE2900   


select COB.Code
from Courses C
left join CoursesBuiltOn COB on COB.BuiltOn = C.Code
left join Grades G on G.Code = C.Code
inner join Students S on S.Sid = G.Sid
where S.Name = 'Mike' and G.Grade = 'F';

Code      
----------
IE2900
```

As you can see in the query above, I wanted to make subqueries that will exclude courses from the whole set of the courses. However, the `NotAvailable` subquery will not exclude `IE2900`. Why is that? I thought I was on the right way... this might not be the most efficient approach touch...

Comment: This sounds like a homework question, have you looked into `INNER` and `OUTER` flavors of the `JOIN` clause. If this is not homework, subqueries using `[NOT] EXISTS` and/or `[NOT] IN` might be better in this scenario.

Comment: It would also help if you posted the query you tried.

Comment: I added what I have so far.

Comment: What is the output of your current query?

Comment: @levelonehuman See OP :-)

Comment: Currently not in a good position to write up a proper response, but take a look at this [explanation of SQL joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/). I think you'll find it helpful in figuring out why your data is being returned the way it is.

Comment: @gmiley I did an attempt, but didn't succeed. See edited OP.

Comment: @levelonehuman Thanks for the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it myself, by cutting the total query into cases:

```
with 
TakenButNotYetPassed as (select Gr.Code 
from Grades Gr 
inner join Students St on St.Sid = Gr.Sid
where St.Name = 'Mike' and Gr.Grade = 'F'
), 
NotAvailable as (select Code
from CoursesBuiltOn
where BuiltOn in TakenButNotYetPassed
), 
Passed as (select Gr.Code
from Grades Gr
inner join Students St on St.Sid = Gr.Sid
where St.Name = 'Mike' and Gr.Grade <> 'F'
)

select *
from Courses C
where C.Dept = 'CS' 
and C.Code not in Passed
and C.Code not in NotAvailable
;
```